# В какой форме употребить глагол "отыскивать"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Он желает порой невозможного, отыскивать то, чего нет.
Или отыскивает то, чего нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант прозвучит глаже, если его немного подшлифовать:
"Он желает порой невозможного. Берётся отыскивать то, чего нет."

Второй вариант я бы изменил на "ищет то, чего нет".

Почему во втором варианте "ищет" звучит лучше, чем "отыскивает"? На это есть две причины. Во-первых, приставка "от-" в данном случае даёт понять, что действие совершилось (в том смысле, что он всё-таки что-то отыскал).  В первом варианте это не так важно, ибо там он лишь *берётся* отыскивать (а отыщет или нет -- отдельный вопрос). Во-вторых, оборот "отыскивает то, чего нет" очень близок к обороту "выискивает то, чего нет". А это уже намёк на паранойю. Таким образом, оборот "отыскивает то, чего нет" даёт нам возможность выискивать в нём дурную коннотацию. :)

Answer (score 5):

Первый вариант предложения допустим, но с ТИРЕ перед инфинитивом:

***Он желает порой невозможного - отыскивать то, чего нет.***

Определение, выраженное неопределённой формой глагола, обособляется (с помощью тире), если оно имеет пояснительное значение и перед ним можно поставить слова *а именно*. [Обособление несогласованнных определений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/715-234_obosoblenie_nesoglasovannyh_opredelenii.html)

Comment: Да, так  вполне приемлемо. Жаль, что нет контекста — было бы понятнее всем. Поддерживаю.

Answer (score 1):

Выбираем **первую форму из двух предложенных,** так как именно она имеет смысл (инфинитив поясняет содержание слова "невозможное").

**Он желает порой невозможного – отыскивать то, чего нет.**

Но надо объяснить семантику этого высказывания (нет ли здесь ошибки).

Какое же значение имеет глагол ***отыскивать***: просто искать что-то трудное или многократно и успешно находить?  См. ответ [Сколько значений у глагола "отыскивать"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448709/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%83-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/448716#448716)

Конечно, наш герой **желает находить, да только как найти то, чего нет?**  Но ведь речь-то  идет только о желании. Вероятно, он **порой** берется за проекты, которые утопичны по своей природе, вот и упрекают его в этом.

Вот и персонаж из романа Достоевского был замечен в стремлении **отыскивать истину** (тоже дело, не сулящее гарантированного успеха):

Способствовало эффекту и то, что господин Прохарчин вдруг, ни с того ни с сего, быв с незапамятных времён почти всё в одном и том же лице, переменил физиономию: лицо стал иметь беспокойное, взгляды пугливые, робкие и немного подозрительные; стал чутко ходить, вздрагивать и прислушиваться и, к довершению всех новых качеств своих, **страх как полюбил отыскивать истину.** [Ф. М. Достоевский. Господин Прохарчин (1846)]

**И теперь мы делаем вывод:** ничего в предложении менять не надо, кроме оформления, смысл же его понятен.

**И посмотрим на принятый ответ.**

1) Подшлифовывать ничего не надо.

2) Приставка ОТ не всегда обозначает завершенность действия, например: Он побежал отыскивать (искать) кого-то.

3) Паранойи тоже никакой нет. Не надо плохо думать о глаголе ***отыскивать*** только потому, что он созвучен глаголу ***выискивать.***