# Сколько значений у глагола "отыскивать"?

Tags: лексика, грамматика

Эта проблема возникла,  когда я просматривала следующий вопрос:

[В какой форме употребить глагол "отыскивать"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448557/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Принятый ответ я не сочла достаточно верным и  решила написать свой ответ. Вот тогда мне и показалось, что у глагола ***отыскивать*** **два значения**,  причем они не прописаны в словарях (Кузнецова, Ефремовой) с достаточной ясностью.

Разные значения глагол имеет, например, **в следующих предложениях:**

(1) Я побежал **отыскивать (= искать)** Курта. На пустыре его не было. [Ю. О. Домбровский (1943-1958)]

(2) Ученые **ухитряются отыскивать (= находить)** неизвестных представителей фауны даже в изученной вдоль и поперек Центральной Европе. [Александр Волков. // «Знание - сила», 2009

Из словарей:

1) **ОТЫСКАТЬ**,  св. кого-что. **Найти**, обнаружить в результате поисков. О. книгу, улицу. (**Отыскивать**)

Отыскать (найти) — отыскивать (находить)?

2) **ОТЫСКИВАТЬ**, несов. перех. **Производя поиски, находить**, обнаруживать, определять местонахождение кого-л., чего-л.  Толковый словарь Ефремовой. 2012

**ОТЫСКАТЬ**, сов. перех. см. отыскивать. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. 2012

А здесь искать или находить?

И еще: **насколько правилен принятый ответ вопроса по ссылке?**

Answer (score 4):

Я солидарен с составителями словарей. Глагол имеет *единственный* смысл - **результативного поиска** (искать + найти, а в несовершенном виде - искать + всякий раз находить /или искать с гарантией нахождения/). В примере из недавнего вопроса слово употреблено неточно: нужен был глагол совершенного вида (брался *отыскать* или *найти*), поскольку "порой" указывает на единичные результативные (в надеждах персонажа) случаи; либо (при желании выразить иной смысл) надо было сказать "начинал/принимался *искать*". "У Домбровского употребление глагола в несовершенной форме можно оправдать тем, что он выражает уверенность рассказчика в результате поиска (и в его процессе, и ретроспективно).

Comment: Alex_ander, большое спасибо за ответ, я как раз на Вас рассчитывала (такие вопросы - это Ваша тема). Теперь вот думаю и над вопросом, и над ответом. Чуть позже отвечу  на ваш комментарий в дополнении к своему ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Всё-таки к словарям у меня остались "претензии", и вот почему.

Обычно носители языка выбирают нужное слово интуитивно, поэтому разные значения глагола ***отыскивать*** в сочетаниях *побежал отыскивать* и *ухитряются отыскивать* реально **существуют и должны быть отражены в словаре.**

Вот и посмотрим, **какие слова относятся к этой теме.** Глаголы ***искать*** несов. вид) и ***найти*** (сов. вид) связаны по смыслу, второй глагол обозначает результат и законченность первого, так как у  ***искать*** нет видовой пары со значением сов. вида.

А вот у глагола ***найти*** видовая пара есть: ***найти – находить***.

**НАЙТИ**, св. 1. кого-что. **В результате поисков обнаружить, отыскать кого-, что-л.** Н. кошелёк в столе. Н. газету. Н. заблудившихся туристов. **Находить,** нсв.

Глагол ***найти*** имеет значение многократности и успешной завершенности  действия, например:  Для хищных птиц умение видеть ультрафиолетовый свет помогает им **находить добычу.**

Итак, глагол ***находить*** выражает  многократность и результативность действия.

Но пара ***отыскать – отыскивать*** сходна с парой ***найти – находить.*** И глагол ***отыскивать*** тоже выражает многократность и результативность действия.

**А отличаются эти пары значениями приставок НА и ОТ**: у ***находить*** нейтральное значение, а вот глагол ***отыскивать*** подразумевает **определенные сложности и затруднения при поиске.** Именно сложность поиска можно считать смысловым **маркером** для  пары ***отыскать – отыскивать.***

**Но эта идея не отражена в словаре.**

Вернемся к нашим предложениям.

(1) **Он побежал отыскивать (искать)  кого-то.** Глагол ***отыскивать*** имеет дополнительную коннотацию, он используется в том случае, если мы заранее знаем, что **поиски будут трудными**. Надо будет искать во многим местах, а конечный результат не гарантирован.

(2) **Они ухитряются отыскивать (находить) неизвестных представителей фауны.** А здесь налицо многократность, результативность и сложность процесса.

**Итак, отыскивать – это (1) много раз успешно находить что-то трудное и (2) искать что-то трудное.**

Comment: Sharon, поддерживаю ответ, спасибо, но я хотел бы заметить, что не стоит предъявлять такие высокие требования к общим толковым словарям. Эти словари не могут (и не должны) углубляться по каждому слову до таких тонкостей. Для этих целей публикуются отдельные статьи и формируются другие, специализированные, словари. Ваш анализ напомнил мне объяснительный словарь синонимов Апресяна. Там нет этой пары слов — там всего-то 350 синонимичных рядов (с более существенными различиями, многие из которых тоже не отражены в словарях). Но и это 1200+ страниц энциклопедического формата. Сами понимаете...